# como redirecciona en nodejs y jade

Tags: html, nodejs, jsp

Archivo app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var middleware = require('./routes/middleware')
var programmers = require('./routes/programmers');
var programmersModel = require('./models/model').programmersModel;
var session = require('express-session');




programmers.setModel(programmersModel);
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(session({

    secret:"user14",
    resave: false,
    saveUnitialized: false
}));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/session', programmers.session);

app.use('/*',middleware.middleware1);

app.use('/app', middleware.middleware2);

//app.get('/*', middleware.middleware3);
app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.formulario);
app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.index);
app.get('/app/programmers/create', programmers.create);
app.post('/app/programmers', programmers.store);
app.get('/app/programmers/:id', programmers.show);
app.get('/app/programmers/:id/edit', programmers.edit);
app.post('/app/programmers/update/:id', programmers.update);
app.post('/app/programmers/delete/:id', programmers.destroy);
app.get('/app/close',programmers.close);
app.listen(8080);

console.log("listenIng http://localhost:8080");
```

Archivo programmers.js

exports.atenderFormulario = function(req, res){
 Programmers.findById(req.params.id, function(error, documento){
        if (error) {
          res.send('Error al intentar ver el formulario.');
        } else {

```
        res.redirect('/atenderFormulario.jsp',{
            programmers: documento
        });
    }
});
```

};

Archivo middleware.js

```
exports.middleware1 = function(req, res ,next){
    next();
}
exports.middleware2 = function(req,res,next){
   next();
}
```

[image: imagen de los directorios]

llamdo en jade

```
a.waves-effect.waves-light.btn-large.red.accent-3(href="../formulario.html"): button(type="button") registrarse
```

Archivo formulario.jsp

REGISTRO

```
<body>
```

|

```
    </header>


    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper teallighten-1">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">ARS-MUSIC</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li>
                    <a href="sass.html"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="badges.html">componentes</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/app/close">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


<h1>Guardar usuarios</h1>
<form  action="/atenderFormulario.jsp" method="post" >
    <div class="form-inline">

            <label for="NOMBRE">NOMBRE</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="Nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE" pattern="[ A-Za-z ]+"
                   title="Este no parece un nombre válido"
                   required>


            <label for="APELLIDO">APELLIDO</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="[ A-Za-z ]+"
                   title="Este no parece un apellido válido"
                   required id="Apellido" name="apellido"  placeholder="APELLIDO">

    <br>
    <br>


        <label for="USUARIO"> NOMBRE DE USUARIO</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  pattern="[ 0-9-A-Za-z ]+"
               title="Este no parece un nombre de usuario válido"
               required id="Nombus" name="user" placeholder="NOMBRE DE USUARIO">



        <label for="CONTRASEÑA">CONTRASEÑA</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contraseña" name="pass" placeholder="Password" pattern="[ 0-9-A-Za-z ]+"
               title="Este no parece una contraseña válida"
               required>

        <label for="edad">edad</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" id="edad" name="edad">

    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" value="masculino" id="test1" name="genero"  />
      <label for="test1">Masculino</label>
        <br>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" value="FEMENINO" id="test2" name="genero"  />
        <label for="test2">Femenino</label>
    </label>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">Registrar</button>
     <a>(href='/app/programmers') Cancelar </a>         

</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando oprimo el botton 
muestra

```
Cannot GET /formulario.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo `app.js`

1. Hay un error de sintaxis en la linea `34`, el `)` debería estar hasta el final de la linea seguido de un `;`. Así:

   ```
   app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.formulario);
   ```
2. También se ve que estas pisando el middleware para *endpoint* `/app/programmers`

   ```
   // Aquí le dices que use 'formulario'
   app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.formulario);
   // Aquí lo pisas diciendole que use 'index'
   app.get('/app/programmers', programmers.index);
   ```

Estructura de proyecto:

1. El archivo `formulario.html` debería estar dentro del directorio `public`

Comment: no sigue con el Cannot GET /formulario.html

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: muchas gracias eso funciono ya puedo visualizar el archivo formulario.html pero tengo lo mismo con el archivo que atiende el formulario ya lo puse en el directorio public tambien

Comment: con el archivo atenderformulario el que debe registrar los datos en la base de datos sale Cannot POST /atenderFormulario.jsp

Comment: @AlexisRodriguezJimenez, *todos aquellos archivos que necesita van a ser accesibles via `URL` deben estar dentro de la carpeta `public`*. De lo contrario se asumen `inexistentes` (o `privados`) y obtendrás un error. Un ejemplo serian los archivos css, img y fonts . Todo los deberás ubicar dentro del directorio public.

Comment: si el esta en la carpeta public pero el archivo es jsp asi que no hay un servidor que lo ejecute creo sabes como puede ejecutarlo

Comment: @AlexisRodriguezJimenez, sinceramente nunca lo he intentado. Te dejo el link a un paquete que te permite [conectar tu server Nodejs a uno Java](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java)

Answer (score 0):

en la linea 34 falta ";"

y prueba modificando asi:

> res.redirect('./formulario');

ya no debes poner la extension

mira aca un ejemplo

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('ingresar', { title: "ingresando..."});
});
```

ingresar es el archivo ingresar.jade

Comment: no funciono sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: @AlexisRodriguezJimenez modifique mi respuesta